# Sage quadratic regression -- numbers too large?

Tags: regression, sage

I am trying to do a (quadratic) regression using Sage and the largest point I have is of this order of magnitude: `(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)` (number of digits shown).

When I run the code:

```
var('a,b,c')
model(x) = a*x^2+b*x+c
find_fit(data,model)
```

(yes, data is already defined)

The fit I get is: `[a == 1.0, b == 1.0, c == 1.0]` which is not even close to correct. Is this because my numbers are too large or is there some other reason?

Comment: When you say "regression," is it because you're doing a regression fit or because it's a regression in Sage's behavior?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri -- I say "regression" because it's a regression fit.

Comment: Could you provide a small example of sample `data` so we can reproduce this?

Comment: By the way, the documentation for `find_fit` says that it uses `scipy.optimize.leastsq`, so Sage may be limited by whatever numerical types `scipy` uses.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri -- I've provided the number of digits in the largest point; you can try something with this. I'll look into the `scipy` thing though.

Comment: You could try calling `scipy.optimize.leastsq` directly and see what happens. The source code for `find_fit` is at https://git.sagemath.org/sage.git/tree/src/sage/numerical/optimize.py#n651, and the documentation for `scipy.optimize.leastsq` is at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html.